# Force a larger image (from a sprite) fits in a smaller div?

Tags: html, css

I have a large image (image sprite) with size 1030px-510px that contains two small images (515px-515px).
I want to get two small images from the sprite and set background for two `<img>` tags. I am using this code:

```css
.img-1, .img-2 {
  width: 515px;
  height: 515px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aozNS.png) no-repeat;
}

.img-1 {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.img-2 {
  background-position: -515px 0px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <img class="img-1">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <img class="img-2">
</div>
```

But the two images larger than my two div (class="col-sm-6"). So, are there any ways to fit my two small images in my two divs?
I don't want to change my two divs to larger (class="col-sm-7").

Comment: Why are you using <img> elements for the background? That's not what <imgs>s are for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `background-size` to 200% (for 2 images), and specify `background-position` in percent:

```css
.img-1, .img-2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aozNS.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 200%;
}

.img-1 {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.img-2 {
  background-position: 100% 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <img class="img-1">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <img class="img-2">
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is my div (class="col-sm-6") smaller than my two images (width: 515px, height: 515px). So, It doesn't work. :(

Comment: @user3089480 Also set `background-size` to 200%

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But It doesn't work. It stretched. :(

Comment: @user3089480 Can you add a code snippet to your question?

Comment: .img-1, .img-2 {
    width: 515px; /*100px works ok*/
    height: 515px; /*100px works ok*/ 
    background: url(images/large-sprite.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 200%;
}

.img-1 {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.img-2 {
    background-position: 100% 0;    
}

Comment: @user3089480 I added a working example in my answer. Isn't that what you were looking for?

Comment: It works when width and height is set to 100px;
It doesn't work when they are set to 515px;

Comment: Why I don't. :(
Could you put your full code please?

Comment: @user3089480 It works but it will show an empty region at the bottom, because the sprite is too small. Is this the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a pixel specific width and height on the images will make them take up that exact space. The bootstrap cols are responsive so they adapt their size to fit the space based on the col number specified (example col-6 or col-4).

If I understand your question correctly then your problem is that you need to remove the 512px width and height css properties on the image and use width: 100% instead. The image will adapt its width to fit the container and the height should adjust to fit the width.

[EDIT] - Never mind that only works if it's an image loaded with src not using the css background property. You might want to consider doing that instead. If you absolutely must do it this way then you can either stay to a small fixed size like the other answer or try using something like flexbox to have the images adapt to the size.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But It doesn't work. I don't know why. :(

Comment: Why do you need to use the background image property? You can take advantage of the image tag's default adaptability if you load with src instead

Comment: Because I want to change background when a user hover on an area of that image. Unfortunately, 515px can't fit good in div(class="col-sm-6"). But with 400px, it works well.

Comment: Ok so I think I found a work around where you can get an image that scales proportionally but allows you to set a background image with css. However it's a bit of a hack. 

You need to use a transparent png image with the proportion that you want (512x512) for example then use that as the src property. Then use the css background property to change the actual image. Here's a fiddle with an example of this: https://jsfiddle.net/animakuz/9d7cganr/

Comment: Btw I didn't set it in the example because the image was a different proportion to the png but if you want the background to scale to fit the box you need to set background-size: 100% or since you're using sprites to 200%.